# Creating Objective-C string using stringification

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to create an Objective-C string using the '#' and '##' operators. I've written the following macros:

```
#define OBJCKEY(p, s) p ## s
#define KEY(k) OBJCKEY(@, #k)
```

Which I'm trying to use in a function in the following way:

```
NSString *key = KEY(EnumValue1);
```

But Xcode reports the following error:

```
Pasting formed '@"EnumValue1"', an invalid preprocessing token
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Note: I'm using the LLVM compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea on how to fix this?

Is there anything wrong with

```
NSString* key = @"EnumValue1";
```

Or how about

```
#define KEY(k) (@#k)

NSString* key = KEY(EnumValue1);
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with it. I was wondering why I was getting this error when trying to do the concatenation but '#define KEY(k) (@#k)' does the trick. Thanks.